# Watch YouTube video inside Blender

Tags: interface

Is there a plugin that allow watching a youtube video inside blender ? This could be quite convenient when watching tutorial to have the video available.

Comment: You would have to have a local copy of the file as Image Textures do not allow URLs, and in fact you cannot even get a direct video URL from youTube.  you could use some video capture tool to produce the local MP4 or WMV file, but then again you'd have to be "playing" the timeline at full speed, which is another impediment, and imposition on what you might be editing.  Short answer: no.  I'd say your best option is to use a PIP (Picture In Picture mode of your browser so that you can have the video available and "On Top" of your blender session.

Comment: You could upload it and put it in the Video Sequencer, if your screen is large enough it will work fine